# ForEach with Array of Custom Views inside ViewBuilder in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-foreach

I am new to iOS Development.Here I am trying to go for different destination views using foreach loop

```
struct NewView : View
{
var arrayofviews //here I need array of views
var body:some View
{
  List
  {
   ForEach(array)
   {(item) in
      NavigationLink(destination: item)
      {
       Text("Click Here")
      }
   }
  }
}
}
```

I tried following

```
var arrayofviews=[view1(),view2(),view3()] as! [Any]
```

then I am getting this error **Cannot convert value of type 'view1' to expected element type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'AnyView')**

here view1,view2,view3 are custom views

```
struct view1:View
{
var body:Some View
{
Text("...")
...
}
}
//similarly view2 and view3 also
```

Comment: This would be easier if you had a common view and made an array of it, `var arrayofviews = [MyView("view1"), MyView("view2"), MyView("view3")]`. You could also ask yourself if it is worth it instead of creating multiple navigation links without a loop.

Comment: try using var arrayofviews=[AnyView(view1()),AnyView(view2()),AnyView(view3())] as! [Any]

Answer (score 2):

```
struct NewView : View
{
var arrayofviews=[AnyView(view1()),AnyView(view2()),AnyView(view3())] as! [AnyView] //This helped
var body:some View
{
  List
  {
   ForEach(0..<array.count)
   {(index) in
      NavigationLink(destination: array[index])
      {
       Text("Click Here")
      }
   }
  }
}
}
```

Thanks 'Mohammad Rahchamani' for your suggestion !!!